# Insert into SQL table data from another table data through NetBeans

Tags: javascript, java, sql, netbeans

I want to insert SQL table data from another SQL table data through NetBeans. I want that when I would to like to press actionbutton then it should be insert into SQL table data (insertdata2) from SQL table (EventLog).

Table 1 : EventLog 
EventId (int)
ObjectId (varchar 50)
Name (varchar 50)
Value (varchar 50)

Table 2 : insertdata2
Id (int)
ObjectId (varchar 50)
Name(Varchar 50)
Value(varchar50)

Here is my button code:

```
      DoConnect();
      st=conn.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery("insert into insertdata2 (ObjectId,insertdata2.Name,insertdata.Value) select top 5 EventLog.ObjectId,EventLog.Name,EventLog.Value from EventLog order by EventId desc");           

        rs=st.executeQuery("select top 50  EventId,ObjectId,Name,Value from insertdata2 order by Id desc ");

        jTable1.setModel(net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); }
 catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);  }
```

But it's showing error : "the statement did not did not return a result set"

Comment: insert doesn't return a resultset. Use `executeUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing. You should use `executeUpdate()` when you trigger an `insert`.
So you can try something like this:

```
final String INSERT_SQL = 
            "insert into insertdata2 (ObjectId,insertdata2.Name,insertdata.Value) select top 5 EventLog.ObjectId,EventLog.Name,EventLog.Value from EventLog order by EventId desc";
connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL).executeUpdate();

rs=st.executeQuery("select top 50  EventId,ObjectId,Name,Value from insertdata2 order by Id desc ");
```

Not that I've executed the `insert` SQL before I select the new data.

Comment: Please, accept it as answer, I'm doing a job interview and my stackoverflow points count a lot.

Comment: OK  , actually I am new in stackoverflow.  How should I accept your answer in this question?

Comment: Thanks,  you just click into the gray V icon at the left.